# Linux Kernel Driver Compilation Error on STM32MP1

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying to compile a kernel module in Yocto on a STM32MP1 target. I can compile a *helloworld* example without problem. But as soon as I want to compile following:

```c
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <linux/module.h
#include <linux/types.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Robert W. Oliver II");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple example Linux module.");
MODULE_VERSION("0.01");

static struct platform_device *pdev;

static int __init fake_eth_add(void)
{
    int inst_id = 0;
    pdev = platform_device_alloc("fake-eth", inst_id);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit fake_eth_put(void)
{
}

module_init(fake_eth_add);
module_exit(fake_eth_put);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> root@txmp-1570:/home/rdm/ethtest# make
> make -C /lib/modules/5.7.1/build M=/home/rdm/ethtest modules
> make[1]: Entering directory '/lib/modules/5.7.1/build'
> MODPOST 1 modules
>
> ERROR: modpost: "platform_device_alloc" [/home/rdm/ethtest/eth-ins.ko] undefined!
> make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [Makefile:1642: modules] Error 2
> make[1]: Leaving directory '/lib/modules/5.7.1/build'
> make: *** [Makefile:9: modules] Error 2

The header *platform_device.h* file is there, but no **.c* module as it should be in a *platform_device.c* file.

My question is, do I need to do any parameter settings in the kernel? If yes, which would it be? So far I didn't find anything with google help regarding *platform_device* and kernel settings.

Comment: `grep platform_device_alloc /proc/kallsyms` shows it defined for me.  Make sure CONFIG_MODULES is defined.